# How to not apply styles to a particular element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the next scenario

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>text text text</p>
    <p>text text text</p>
    <p><cite>author cite</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

I am trying to select just the `p` elements that are inside of `blockquote` but not contain child `cite` elements to add a `"` before and after every `p` element

my approach is

```css
blockquote p:not(:has(> cite))::before,
blockquote p:not(:has(> cite))::after
{
  content: '"';
}
```

but it is not working as it still has [no support yet](https://caniuse.com/css-has), anyone can give me a hand? Thank you in advance

EDIT:
I want to point, It is not possible to modify the HTML by adding some class to `p` elements because the HTML is provided from a remote server.

Comment: i think is impossible, why don't use js?

Comment: If its from a remote server , you should be probably using an iframe . And You can not change the styles of the page that resides within the iframe. Or are you doing a webscrap in your server of other websites and forwarding to your your site by appending some stylesheets ?

Comment: @sandrin joy The server parses a txt file and extracts the data, then it converts to HTML and it stores to a DB and after that is provided to the client app through API that resides in a server. I don't need an iframe, I have access to the HTML code in the client but it shouldn't be modified, anyway, this is not the scope of the question.

Comment: "I have access to the HTML code in the client but it shouldn't be modified" - but isn't this (changing css)  a part of modifying html. ?

Comment: @SandrinJoy Maybe I am wrong but IMO, modify the CSS it is not understood as modify the HTML

Answer (score 3):

I have given two solutions for `jquery` and `javascript`. These decisions have the same principle.

In this code, the parent `<p>` is accessed from the assigned tag `<cite>`, with the subsequent assignment of class `no-content` with the missing `content:` parameter:

```
.no-content:before,
.no-content:after {
  content: none;
}
```

Default `html` structure.

- jquery solution:

```js
$('cite').closest('p').addClass('no-content');
```

```css
blockquote p::before,
blockquote p::after
{
  content: '"';
}

.no-content:before,
.no-content:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>
    <p>text text text</p>
    <p>text text text</p>
    <p><cite>author cite</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

- javascript solution:

```js
document.querySelector('cite').closest('p').classList.add('no-content');
```

```css
blockquote p::before,
blockquote p::after
{
  content: '"';
}

.no-content:before,
.no-content:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>text text text</p>
    <p>text text text</p>
    <p><cite>author cite</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: As this question is about CSS I can not mark it as the correct solution, but it is a very good solution using javascript.

Comment: @Raikish, Thanks for your feedback. But you will not solve your problem correctly without css. If there is a solution for css, then this solution will be a "crutch". If you want the right solution, then use the javascript solution.

Answer (score 3):

A hacky idea to hide the content with the `cite` element

```css
blockquote p::before,
blockquote p::after {
  content: '"';
}

blockquote p cite {
  background: #fff; /* this need to match the main background */
  margin: 0 -6px; /* a trial and error value, you need to adjust it based on your font*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <p><cite>author cite</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to hide the `cite` element. This doesn't solve it.

Comment: @TimonNetherlands where did you see that I am hiding the cite?

Comment: Yes. I took a look, I take it back. Nice one.

Comment: The problem is when he change child

Comment: @SimoneRossaini can you explain better what you mean by changing the child?

Comment: if for example he change cite with div the code will not work. 
basically only if it is static it works

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve that. You can add CSS selectors, such as classes to the `p` tags you want to surround with the content.

HTML:

```html
<blockquote>
  <p class="quote">text text text</p>
  <p class="quote">text text text</p>
  <p><cite>author cite</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

CSS:

```css
.quote::after,
.quote::before {
  content: '"';
}
```

or if you prefer just using elements as selectors, you can select the last `p` to remove it's quote:

CSS:

```css
blockquote p::last-child:after,
blockquote p::last-child:before {
  content: none;
}
```

Or with the same result:

```css
blockquote p span::before,
blockquote p span::after
{
  content: '"';
}
```

Comment: I can not modify the HTML because it is provided from some server, also in some situations the `cite` is not in the last `p` of the `blockquote`

Comment: Can you use javascript? Then some of us might be able to come with a solution in javscript. Look at sergey kuznetsov's response for example.

Comment: I did some digging and on MDN and CSS selectors and I found nothing that could help you. I am sorry :/. The closest I got was a selector called [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but sadly it doesn't work but you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The closest option CSS offers is `blockquote p *:not(cite)`. The problem is that the wildcar selector `*` selects anything but text nodes, so it doesn't help.

Unfortunately, the `:empty` select does exactly that, as in it does lookup text nodes so `blockquote p:empty` also won't work since it doesn't consider any of the `p` elements to lack children.

Luckily, a new selector is scheduled to appear, namely `:has` which will allow to perform selections like `blockquote p:not(:has > cite)`. We're not there yet so until then adding a span to your `p` elements may be a solution:

```
  <blockquote>
    <p><span>text text text<span></p>
    <p><span>text text text</span></p>
    <p><cite>author cite</cite></p>
  </blockquote>
```

In CSS:

```
blockquote p *:not(cite)::before,
blockquote p *:not(cite)::after
{
  content: '"';
}
```

Or with the same result:

```
blockquote p span::before,
blockquote p span::after
{
  content: '"';
}
```